# Maven remote repository with releases and snapshots tags

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven enable Eclipse (Mars) which has below repository in it:

```
     <repository>
        <id>sonatype.oss.snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>false</releases>
        <snapshots>true</snapshots>
    </repository>
```

It works fine, how ever when I try to run a goal on maven from command line (maven 3.0 or 3.3) I got this error:

> [ERROR]  Some problems were encountered while processing the
>   POMs: [ERROR] Malformed POM E:\workspace\Saba\pom.xml: expected
>   START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...\r\n\t
>   false

When I remove the `<releases>false</releases>` and `<snapshots>true</snapshots>` tags it works fine. 
I have seen the `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd` the `release` and `snapshots` tags are valid tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
        <repository>
        <id>sonatype.oss.snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Comment: In the XSD file there's a complex-type for "releases" and "snapshots". This complex-type is elsewhere defined. In there it specifies the <enabled> blocks.